# Exceeding unsigned boundary

Tags: c, ansi-c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
unsigned char a=250,b=20, c;
c=a+b;
printf ("%d\n",c);
return 0;
}
```

What can I do for it to show 270?
Besides declaring c as int.

Comment: ... use a larger type?

Comment: a,b,c must remain defined as unsigned chars.

Comment: `puts("270");`.

Comment: You can use `short` =)

Comment: Just print `a+b` instead of `c`

Comment: Why must `a`, `b`, and `c` be defined as `unsigned char`? What other restrictions haven't you told us about? `puts("270")` solves the problem as stated; if that doesn't answer your question, you'll need to state the problem more clearly.

Comment: @Nirk, That still results in an `unsigned char`.

Comment: @chris: No, it doesn't; the operands of `+` are promoted to `int`.

Comment: Another silly solution: Compile and run the program on a system with `CHAR_BIT > 8`. (Good luck finding one!)

Comment: Or `#define char int` just before the declaration.

Comment: @KeithThompson, Oh, shoot, I keep forgetting it does that for types smaller than `int`. If you did this with `unsigned int + unsigned int`, it would stay that.

Comment: the "Just print a+b instead of c" is ok I guess

Comment: @Keith: Undefined behaviour.

Comment: @AssuraTheorycraft: Now help us by clarifying just what you were asking for.

Comment: At a job interview I received this problem, they wanted to see if I could bypass the boundary restrictions of char, I wasn't allowed to modify the types, or at least not within the declaration part.

Comment: @DeadMG: Actually `#define char int`, though it's a horribly bad idea, doesn't cause undefined behavior unless it occurs prior to the inclusion of standard header or to the expansion of any macro defined in a standard header. C11 7.1.2p4. Did I mention that it's still a horribly bad idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unsigned char's (*assuming char is only eight bits*) can only represent 2<sup>8</sup> numbers, from 0 to 255. You'll need to use another type such as `int` to represent this.

Comment: i was hoping for something a little more clever, as I stated, I don't wish to define c as int

Comment: More clever? `puts("270")` is the best answer for a _clever_ response. `printf("%d\n", a + b);` is the next best, as it should convert the result to an int for you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry but you just can't , an unsigned char can hold a maximum of 255

Comment: It's not clear that the value `270` ever has to be stored in an object of type `unsigned char`. One comment suggests `puts("270");`; another suggests `printf("%d\n", a+b);`. Either will work.

Comment: is type casting useful for example? after declaring can I convert the unsigned char to an int? or some other method?

Comment: @KeithThompson I know but I'm talking about the possibility of storing that number in an unsigned char (and you didn't have to vote down to say that)

Comment: @FaroukJouti: Could have been someone else. (It’s best to leave votes out of things for the most part)

Comment: @AssuraTheorycraft no that won't work either because in this case their will be a loss of information

Comment: @FaroukJouti: In that case, no cast is necessary, since the result of `a + b` is already of type `int`. (And I didn't downvote your answer; please don't make assumptions.)

Comment: @FaroukJouti: It's not related to gcc; it's required by the C standard. (Actually `a + b` is of type `unsigned int` if `UCHAR_MAX > INT_MAX`, but that's impossible for a system with 8-bit bytes.)

Comment: @KeithThompson Yeah I just realized how wrong (stupid ?) I am , it took this much to realize , you're absolutely right the sum of both variables is an int :)